# jQuery/Javascript: setInterval check if DOM element exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

var check;
        function showLoader() {
            $('#mc_signup_form').prepend(' loading …');
            check_init(); 
        }

```
    function check_init() {
        check = setInterval('check_trigger()', 300);
    }

    function check_clear() {
        clearInterval(check);
    }

    function check_trigger() {
        if ( $('.mc_error_msg').length == 0 || $('.mc_success_msg').length == 0 ) {
            $('#mc_signup_form .loading').remove();
            check_clear();
        }
    }
```

i wonder why my browser keeps telling me that check_trigger() doesn't exist?
I'm initiating a setInterval inside of my showLoader() function. It should trigger check_trigger. When one of the two divs (.mc_error_msg or .mc_success_msg) exists i want to clear the Interval.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you try to put check_trigger() above check_init()?

Comment: @mathiregister, what's the scope of the code? because setInterval() would be running under "window" / global object, it might not find check_trigger().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find passing strings to `setTimeout` and `setInterval` just leads to problems :)

Try:

```
setInterval(check_trigger, 300);
```

Comment: Yeah, just pass the function directly :)

Answer (score 1):

it should be check_trigger only remove outside the single or double quote...

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid double evaluation**

By putting that function into `quotes`, ECMA-/Javascript will `eval` that code, which is just unbelievable slow'ish. So always use a `function reference` withing `setTimeout` / `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function(){
    check_trigger();
}, 300);
```

or directly

```
setInterval(check_trigger, 300);
```

If you remove the elements in question by yourself somewhere, it might be an interesting approach to **hook** the `jQuery .remove()` or `.detach()` method (If you call those to remove the element).

That could look like:

```
var hookRemove = $.fn.remove;

$.fn.remove    = function(){
    if(this.id === 'something'){
       // hoorray! we found it
    }

    hookRemove.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Remember your're dealing with an `jQuery object` within the hook. So actually `this` could also be a `wrapped set` of elements. Therefore a call to

```
this.each(function(){
});
```

within the hook should be more save for checking. That way you have an `exact` knowledge of when an object is removed without an `intervall timer`.

Answer (score 1):

also use setTimeout instead of setInterval so you can get rid of the global variable

Answer (score 1):

Combining the various suggestions here is as simplified version which should work regardless of the scope in which it is defined.

```
function showLoader () {
    $('#mc_signup_form').prepend('<span class="loading"> loading &hellip;</span>');
    setTimeout (function check_trigger () {
      if ( $('.mc_error_msg').length == 0 || $('.mc_success_msg').length == 0 ) {
        $('#mc_signup_form .loading').remove();
      } else {
        setTimeout (check_trigger, 300);
      }   
    }, 300); 
}
```